# jquery live() or on() failed to handle objects without events

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a button`. on` clicking it appends a class having `draggable` into the container. 
The div having `draggable` class is assigned the `jquery draggable()` in order to make it `draggable`.

However the objects created during run time is not becoming `dragable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign `draggable` to dynamic elements, try following statement after creating and appending those `draggable` to `document`:

```
$('.class_to_dynamic_element').draggable('destroy').draggable();
```